# Output redirected from Get-ChildItem to Compress-Archive does not archive all files/preserve folder structure

Tags: powershell, get-childitem, compress-archive

```
GetChildItem "C:\foo\bar" -Recurse -File | where { $_.Name -notmatch '[a-zA-Z_0-9^0-9]*(.pl|.xap|.go|.zip|.py|.tar|.gz|.tgz)' } | Compress-Archive -DestinationPath "C:\archive\xyz.zip"
```

When I execute the `GetChildItem` command without output redirection, the command is returning exactly what I need. However when I redirect the output to `Compress-Archive`, this cmdlet does not preserve the directory structure (all files are archived at the root) of `\bar` and does not include all of the files when the `GetChildItem` command is executed in isolation.

Would appreciate any input. I would typically use unix shell command(s), however I am restricted by my environment.

Update (3/4/19):

```
GetChildItem "C:\foo\bar" -Recurse | where { $_.Name -notmatch '[a-zA-Z_0-9^0-9]*(.pl|.xap|.go|.zip|.py|.tar|.gz|.tgz)' } | Compress-Archive -DestinationPath "C:\archive\xyz.zip"
```

Removing the -File switch/argument resolves the folder structure issue, but files that I want to ignore in the `-notmatch` switch are no longer ignored. Given the following example:

```
/archive
    -/a
       -file.pl
    -/b
       -file.py
       -file1.html
    -index.html
    -some_junk.zip
```

This command will produce the following output:

```
VERBOSE: Preparing to compress...
VERBOSE: Performing the operation "Compress-Archive" on target "
C:\archive\a
C:\archive\b".
VERBOSE: Adding 'C:\archive\a\file.pl'.
VERBOSE: Adding 'C:\archive\b\file.py'.
VERBOSE: Adding 'C:\archive\b\file1.html'.
VERBOSE: Adding 'C:\archive\index.html'.
VERBOSE: Adding 'C:\archive\some_junk.zip'.
```

In this case the .py, .zip, and .pl files are being included in the .zip

Comment: I would suggest changing all curly 'smart-quotes' to straight ones. You have probably copied this from some internet page or modified it in Word?

Comment: @Theo: I am going to assume you mean the use of `'` vs `\``

Realized I wrote this post on my phone which inserted the smart-quotes. I updated the post.

Comment: ..I stil see smart-quotes around `“C:\foo\bar”` and `“C:\archive\xyz.zip”`. Untested, but perhaps by removing the `-File` switch from the `Get-ChildItem` cmdlet will allow for also sending the folder objects through the pipeline? Now it just sends file objects to `Compress-Archive`. You can test by appending a `-WhatIf` switch at the very end.

Comment: @Theo: Thanks for the -WhatIf flag, will come in handy.

When I removed the -File argument, the entire directory is sent to Compress-Archive and does not ignore any files under that directory.

Comment: I don't think your regex does what you expect of it. Maybe try `[a-z_0-9^]+(\.pl|\.xap|\.go|\.zip|\.py|\.tar|\.gz|\.tgz)$`

Comment: Tried it, still the same.

Comment: Ended up switching to a unix distribution and using the `zip` binary/package with the `-x` flag